Failing to use paho.mqtt library in python in mininet-wifi's Stations to connect to mqtt broker in another Station
I created an subclass SmartDevice with the hope to simulate an IOT enviroment where the SmartDevice publishes messages in the broker topic every X interval o time, and also reads the command topic to get instructions from the broker
def connect_with_broker(self, broker_ip):
        self.broker_ip = broker_ip
        
        self.mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2)
        self.mqtt_client.on_message   = self.on_message
        self.mqtt_client.on_connect   = self.on_connect
        self.mqtt_client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe

        info(f"trying to connect to :{broker_ip}")
        try:

            self.mqtt_client.connect(broker_ip, port=1883, keepalive=60)
            self.mqtt_client.subscribe("commands")
            self.mqtt_client.loop_start()
            info(f"{self.name} linked to broker at {self.broker_ip}\n")
            

            self.connected = True

        except Exception as e:
            info(f"Error connecting to MQTT Broker: {str(e)}\n")
        

This is the connect with broker function that once executed should connect the paho.mqtt client to the broker, but always when i try using it in this context i get the error
trying to connect to :10.0.0.1Error connecting to MQTT Broker: timed out
class MQTTServer(Station):
    def __init__(self, name, **params):
        super(MQTTServer, self).__init__(name, **params)
        self.mqtt_port = 1883
        self.log_file = f"/tmp/mosquitto_{name}.log"
    
    def start_broker(self):
        command = f'mosquitto -p {self.mqtt_port} -d -v --bind-address 0.0.0.0 > {self.log_file} 2>&1'
        retorno = self.cmd(command)
        info(f"return : {retorno} \nopen to messagens in {self.IP()}:{self.mqtt_port}\n")

    def stop_broker(self):
        self.cmd('killall mosquitto')

    def read_logs(self):
        # Read and return the content of the log file
        try:
            with open(self.log_file, 'r') as file:
                return file.read()
        except IOError as e:
            return str(e)


def topology():
    net = Mininet_wifi()

    ap1 = net.addAccessPoint('ap1')
    sta1 :MQTTServer  = net.addStation('sta1', cls=MQTTServer , ip='10.0.0.1')
    sta2 :SmartDevice = net.addStation("sta2", cls=SmartDevice, ip='10.0.0.2')

    net.configureWifiNodes()

    #inicia server mqtt
    

    net.addLink(ap1, sta1)
    net.addLink(ap1, sta2)

    sta1.start_broker()
    net.start()
    
    

    sta2.connect_with_broker(sta1.IP())
    #sta2.turn_on()

    CLI(net)

    time.sleep(1)
    sta2.turn_off()
    sta1.stop_broker()
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    topology()


This is how i am setting up the topology
I tried using xterm sta1 sta2 mid mininet execution and i could ping an use mosquitto_sub/pub without problems, so it's not an reache problem but when i try to py sta2.connect_with_broker(sta1.IP()) the same error persists
for mor context below is my MQTTServer code
class MQTTServer(Station):
    def __init__(self, name, **params):
        super(MQTTServer, self).__init__(name, **params)
        self.mqtt_port = 1883
    
    def start_broker(self):
        command = f'mosquitto -p {self.mqtt_port} -d -v'
        retorno = self.cmd(command)
        info(f"return : {retorno} \nopen to messagens in {self.IP()}:{self.mqtt_port}\n")

    def stop_broker(self):
        self.cmd('killall mosquitto')



What version of mosquitto are you using and what is the log output? Best guess is that mosquitto is only listening on 127.0.0.1 is it's v2.0.x
